# How to keep yourself warm

Tags: clothing, comfort, temperature

I commute early morning in bus and train which means waiting and I live in Europe so it mean minus degrees. I m wearing jeans and formal shirt with jumper/sweater on top and runners as footwear. Even in train I feel myself shivering.

I know my clothing sense is bad, but how can I make myself stay warm during early morning and cold evenings.?

Comment: Can you clarify for your post? — Do you feel your clothing choice/warmth is appropriate for the temperature? It's not clear from your question what's *thwarting* common sense suggestions like "dress warmer." See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Um, I'm not seeing any mention of a coat in your clothing description - if you're not wearing a winter coat, I'm not  surprised you're cold - add a coat, gloves and a scarf and you'll be much warmer.

Comment: @Bamboo are winter coats different than summer coats ?

Comment: Of course they are! They're usually made out of wool mixtures and look smart, or are padded anorak/duvet type coats which are even warmer, coming down to your knees or mid thigh, sometimes longer, mid calf say, whereas a summer coat is made of thin, light material, or is a raincoat or just a light, short jacket made out of thin cotton or linen. Even in the temperate UK, if I wore my heavy winter coat in summer, I'd expire of heat exhaustion... Surely you've seen people wearing coats in winter in Europe...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside or inside? Inside use a blanket. Outside use undergarments. Here in the US we have special material clothes that tight fit to the skin are thin and light yet breathable, they keep in the heat. I picked some up from the store there is a shirt and pants. They are black, thin and light. You wear it underneath your clothes. I just looked up the package, it's called "omni-wool". I am sure there are many brands of the same kind of thing if that isn't available in your country.

When I was a kid we had a lower-tech version of these, we called them "long-johns". It is the best way to add extra layers, and with modern material fabrics that retain heat better and are lighter and thinner, there is zero impact to mobility and you can't even tell you're wearing extra, yet you are far warmer. If one set is not enough wear a second layer, they are thin enough. With two layers underneath jeans and a jacket you are going to be sweating even in 0 (F) weather.

Note:

Some other tips:

Your feet cold? Double socks, or also the omni wool has socks too to go under your socks or replace your socks.

Your hands cold? Modern gloves are thin and light and even cheap yet have multiple layers and some are even waterproof, and can be rated to negative weather without losing mobility.

Your neck cold? Time for a scarf.

Your face cold? Wear a big hat, and if you are really really cold it's time for a balaclava. Save that for when you aren't worried about people thinking you're a robber :P

Here is some documentation on the omni-wool material (from their website):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add a layer under your clothes, as that might be too warm in the heated place of work, add a layer over your street clothes when you go out.
Waterproof trousers over your jeans and a rain jacket over your winter jacket will add a lot of warmth, when arriving or when in the train you can just take them off.

For your feet you need shoes that are designed to keep your feet warm rather than running shoes that are designed to let your feet cool down when running.
Proper leather dress shoes are one step up, mountain boots two or three. Moonboots are a step up too much if you ask me.
And keep your head warm, hat, scarf, even headphones which are big enough to act as ear muffs might work.

If your place of work is also cold in winter, add a layer under your clothes. This can be thermo underwear, but thin training trousers or (silk) pajama pants and an extra long sleeved t-shirt are likely to be enough if it is just below freezing outside.

Comment: Thick-soled winter boots will keep your feet warm. You can add thermal soles for extra therms. If your office is nice and warm take some Birkenstocks to work, so you don't have to clonk around in boots all day. Buy boots with plenty of room for thick socks. Try motorcycle socks, come up to your knees. Again, you'll want to take them off once you get to the office.

Comment: When I talk about cold in Western Europe, it is only a few degrees under freezing point, and that is what I read in the question as well. Thick soled winterboots and extra thermal inlays are not (usually) needed there, nor are several layers of thick socks, for a travel that is mostly in bus and train. The other answer is for the real cold situations, where you might freeze if you are not careful.

Comment: I live in South Germany, and it's often well under zero in winter.

Answer (score 0):

To me you are definitely underdressed for weather below +10 C - especially when it rains/snows and/or is windy.   Think about where you lose body heat - it's mostly from your extremities (head, hands, feet).  It's also quite important that you remain as dry as possible at all times.  Waiting for the bus with cold damp feet (even at +5 C) can become a real misery.
If you only do one thing - wear something like a ski toque (wool cap) on your head.  Something like 35% of heat loss is from the head, leading to this bit of folk wisdom around here (central Canada where -20 C is common): If you want warm feet - cover your head.
Runners are a bad choice, replace them with warmer(and dampness resistant) footwear and wear gloves (or better yet, mittens).
Wear any coat you have over the sweater, if only to block the wind/rain; both are great stealers of body heat. This is an example of how to use layers to beat the cold (add/remove layers as needed).

Do you know somone who plays winter sports - skating, skiing, etc.? If so, ask them for what works (they'll be familiar with all of the above suggestions).  And/or do some web searches for subjects like "winter sports clothes".

BTW for women it comes down to a choice of being warm or being stylish  I'm sure you can figure out what choice almost all Canadian women make - and what choice ALL Canadian men make.